# Read lines between two keywords

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

Can someone suggest what to do if I have to read between two  keywords like

```
*System_Power
1
1.2
1.8
2
*System_Terminate
```

In this case the asnwer would be

```
1
1.2
1.8
2
```

I tried using awk like

```
awk '$0 =="*System_Power"               #  start printing when 1st field is *System_Power
$0 != "*System_Terminate"{              #  until reach the  *System_Terminate
print;   } ' powerSummary > reportedFailure.k    # Read from file powerSummary and pipe to reportedFailure.k
exit
```

where the above data is found somewhere in the middle of file powerSummary.

I would be thankful for your corrections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work for you:

```
$ awk '/\*System_Power/{f=1;next}/\*System_Terminate/{f=0}f' infile
1
1.2
1.8
2
```

Comment: it worked for me, but I am not able to find a general way of awk-ing  . Everytime I get a new format of solution which is quite hard to digest. Trying to get it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sed` to trivially select the text between two matching lines, but this will also include the matching lines themselves...so we explicitly delete those:

```
sed -n '/System_Power/,/System_Terminate/ { 
    /^\*/ d
    p
}' < input
```

Awk can also select the text between matching lines:

```
awk '/System_Power/,/System_Terminate/ {print}' < input
```

...but like `sed` this will include the start/end terminators.  You can fix this with `awk`, but I think you get a cleaner solution with `sed`.

Comment: Is there a reason why you use redirection instead of sed/awk parameters ?  For me those can be written `sed ... input` or `awk ... input` without the `<`.

Comment: Nope, no reason.  Just in a filterin' sort of mood.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another one:

```
awk '$1=="*System_Power",$1=="*System_Terminate" {if (!/System*/) print}' in.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sed '/^\*System_Power/,/^\*System_Terminate/!d;//d' file
```

or this:

```
awk '/^\*System_Terminate/{p=0};p;/^\*System_Power/{p=1}' file
```